# Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ without using L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

A student I tutor asked me this question. The L'Hopital's approach is quick and easy, but is there a direct but rigorous way to show this without invoking L'Hopital's?

Comment: You cannot use L'H since the derivative requires knowing the limit.

Comment: The typical proof is geometric and uses the squeeze theorem.

Comment: An elementary and acceptable proof is considering a point P on the unit circle in the first quadrant,  along with it a triangle inside and outside the circle. Considering areas as P moves to the x axis results in the limit. I am sure this can be found somewhere on MSE. I am glad though you see that Hospital is not the way to go.

Comment: See https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ElementaryLimit.shtml and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: Take a look to any calculus book or in frequent question here at MSE.

Comment: I really like this proof on KhanAcademy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xitzTutKqM It isn't as rigorous as other proofs but it's very intuitive. Very easy to explain to a student.

Comment: @hossmeister. What proofs are out there that dont use derivative of sine whatsover, only elementary properties?

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-In the circle of radius $1$ take the figure above and go to the limit.

[image]